# Error with \edef and inner \def,

Tags: macros

I seem to lack understanding the combination of an `\edef` and the definition of a macro inside another definition. This is probably best shown with an example.

The following MWE (I know it is not really useful so minimal) does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\mymacro#1{%
    \def\do##1{##1}%
    #1%
}

\begin{document}
    \edef\savedValue{\mymacro{argument}}%
    savedValue: \savedValue
\end{document}
```

The error is in the `\edef` line and states `Illegal parameter number in definition of \savedValue`.

I thought that the `\edef` would expand `\mymacro{argument}`, which first expands `\def\do##1{##1}` to nothing leading to the output `argument`, which is then saved into `\savedValue`. Without the line `\def\do##1{##1}` this seems to work as explained, but with that line I get the mentioned error.

What is the problem here?

Using `xparse`'s command does work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mymacro}{m}{%
    \def\do##1{##1}%
    #1%
}

\begin{document}
    \edef\savedValue{\mymacro{argument}}%
    savedValue: \savedValue
\end{document}
```

and gives the expected output: [image: result]

What is the actual difference to using `\def`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the `\def` operation is not expandable. In an `\edef` `\def` is simply a non-expandable token that stays unchanged. Similarly `\mymacro` ends up being defined by `\protected\def` so does not expand in an `\edef`.

```
\show\mymacro
```

shows

```
> \mymacro=\protected macro:
#1->\def \do ##1{##1}#1.
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mymacro}{m}{%
    \def\do##1{##1}%
    #1%
}

\begin{document}
    \edef\savedValue{\mymacro{argument}}%
    savedValue: \savedValue
\end{document}
```

So there are no expandable tokens in the definition of `\savedValue` so the `\edef` is equivalent to `\def` in this case. `\show\savedValue` shows

```
   > \savedValue=macro:
->\mymacro {argument}.
```

Then when `\savedValue` is expanded it is equivalent to

```
\def\do#1{#1}argument
```

---

If you use `\def` rather than `\protected\def` then when you get to the `\edef` `mymacro` expands (but `\def` doesn't so it is the same as

```
\edef\savedValue{\mymacro{argument}}%
```

is

```
\edef\savedValue{\def\do##1{##1}argument}%
```

then it tries to expand `\def` but that is not expandable so it is left, then it tries to expand `\do` so you get the expansion of whatever random definition `\do` has at this point  which happens to be

```
 \do=\noexpand.
```

and things go wrong....

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Is there a standard trick to "remove" the inner `\def`. Maybe I am thinking to complicated but there seems to be much benefit it that were possible.

Comment: No once you have an unprotected definition that includes def it is the classic latex "fragile command' and "\edef" is the classic "moving argument". The solution to that is to use `\protect` to prevent the macro expanding. etex `\protected\def` as used by the expl3 command and the classic latex `\DeclareRobustCommand` mechanism both set things up so the macro automatically does not expand in the moving argument to save using `\protect` explictly. Searching fro "fragile command in a moving argument" on this site or via google will reveal lots of hits with further information:-)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility to avoid the problems explained by David Carlisle is to completely avoid the `\edef`. The trick is to put the saving inside of the "called function". This is a bit similar to C, where a pointer to the allocated memory is given as the first argument to a function and is normally an input-output-parameter. This pattern can probably save a lot of trouble with LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\def\mymacro#1#2{%
    \def\do##1{##1}%
    \csdef{#1}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
    \mymacro{savedValue}{argument}%
    savedValue: \savedValue
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's `\def\do##1{##1}` supposed to do?

Comment: Serving as the placeholder for an MWE. In reality it would be the definition of a more complex \do macro, which is used in a \forcsvlist call.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\mymacro#1{%
    \def\do##1{##1}%
    #1%
}

\begin{document}
    \edef\savedValue{\mymacro{argument}}%
    savedValue: \savedValue
\end{document}
```

Two facts are relevant for the explanation:

1. When a macro is expanded whose *⟨definition text⟩* contains sequences of hashes, then the amount of hashes in these sequences will be halved in the result of expanding the macro.
   With the code of your example `\mymacro{⟨argument⟩}` yields  `\def\do#1{#1}⟨argument⟩`. The amount of hashes in all sequences `##` of the *⟨definition text⟩* of `\mymacro` is halved to `#` in the result of expanding `\mymacro`.
2. `\def` is not expandable, therefore will not be removed from the token stream but will be left untouched during `\edef`-expansion. (Unless an expandable control sequence is expanded during `\edef`-expansion whose expansion yields removal of the `\def`-token as is the case with `\gobble` in the following: `\def\gobble#1{} ... \edef\foo{\gobble\def whatsoever}`.)

With `\edef\savedValue{\mymacro{argument}}` expandable tokens of the sequence `\mymacro{argument}` are expanded until no expandable tokens are left before the assignment takes place.

`\def` is not expandable. Therefore just expanding all expandable tokens in/coming from `\mymacro{argument}` yields:

```
\def⟨total expansion of all expandable tokens in the sequence "\do#1{#1}argument" ⟩
```

If `\do` is defined as something unexpandable, then just expanding all expandable tokens in/coming from `\mymacro{argument}` yields the token-sequence:
`\def\do#1{#1}argument`.

The likelihood is very high that the token-sequence that comes into being during `\edef`-expansion as the expanded *⟨definition text⟩*  contains `#1` although the *⟨parameter text⟩* of the `\edef`-definition of `\savedValue` is empty/does not introduce an argument `#1`.

That's why you get the error  `Illegal parameter number in definition of \savedValue.`

In case `\do` is undefined, you will get the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\mymacro #1->\def \do
```

prior to the error  `Illegal parameter number in definition of \savedValue.`

---

---

The following example might provide better understanding of how `\edef` works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\mymacro#1{%
  \def\do{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\let\do=\relax 
\edef\macro{\mymacro{bar}}
\show\macro
\let\foo=\relax
\def\do{\foo}%
\edef\macro{\mymacro{bar}}
\show\macro
\def\foo{\hoo}%
\let\hoo=\relax
\edef\macro{\mymacro{bar}}
\show\macro
\end{document}
```

Console output:

```
[...]
> \macro=macro:
->\def \do {bar}.
l.8 \show\macro
               
? 
> \macro=macro:
->\def \foo {bar}.
l.12 \show\macro
                
? 
> \macro=macro:
->\def \hoo {bar}.
l.16 \show\macro
                
? 
[...]
```

The following example might provide better understanding of the treatment of sequences of hashes during expansion:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\stringifytillrelax[1]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {}{\string#1\stringifytillrelax}
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\mymacro{##}%
\message{^^JSee the amount of hashes that comes from expanding \string\mymacro: \expandafter\stringifytillrelax\mymacro\relax}%
\def\mymacro{####}%
\message{^^JSee the amount of hashes that comes from expanding \string\mymacro: \expandafter\stringifytillrelax\mymacro\relax}%
\def\mymacro{######}%
\message{^^JSee the amount of hashes that comes from expanding \string\mymacro: \expandafter\stringifytillrelax\mymacro\relax}%
\def\mymacro{########}%
\message{^^JSee the amount of hashes that comes from expanding \string\mymacro: \expandafter\stringifytillrelax\mymacro\relax}%
\edef\mymacrob{\mymacro}
\message{^^JSee the amount of hashes that comes from expanding \string\mymacrob: \expandafter\stringifytillrelax\mymacrob\relax}%
\edef\mymacroc{\mymacrob}
\message{^^JSee the amount of hashes that comes from expanding \string\mymacroc: \expandafter\stringifytillrelax\mymacroc\relax}%
\end{document}
```

Console output:

```
[...]
See the amount of hashes that comes from expanding \mymacro: # 

See the amount of hashes that comes from expanding \mymacro: ## 

See the amount of hashes that comes from expanding \mymacro: ### 

See the amount of hashes that comes from expanding \mymacro: #### 

See the amount of hashes that comes from expanding \mymacrob: ## 

See the amount of hashes that comes from expanding \mymacroc: #
[...]
```